# How to read and connect a csv file to a sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, csv, vb.net-2010

I am looking for ways I can take a csv file read it line by line then take selected coluns and rows and connect them to a mysql database.

I have made the following code however I am unable to connect it to insert in a sql database.

How can I connect this to my db with Columns Time,Name,Location all Varchars?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form4
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim com As New SqlCommand
Dim str As String

Public Sub ReadCSVFile()
    Dim fileIn As String = "C:\Users\FFFF\Downloads\new.csv"
    Dim fileRows(), fileFields() As String
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
    If File.Exists(fileIn) Then
        Dim fileStream As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fileIn)
        fileRows = fileStream.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine)
        For i As Integer = 0 To fileRows.Length - 1
            fileFields = fileRows(i).Split(",")
            If fileFields.Length >= 4 Then
                TextBox1.Text += fileFields(3) & " " & fileFields(2) & " " & fileFields(0) & "<br /> "
            End If
        Next
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = fileIn & " not found."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call ReadCSVFile()
End Sub

Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=FFF-PC;Initial Catalog=MySolution;User Id=sa;Password=sarfar.811;")

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "fileFields(3)")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, "fileFields(2)")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "fileFields(0)")

    Dim strSql As String = "Insert into New_1(Name,Time,Location) values(@Name@Time,@Location)"


    Dim dAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    dAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd
    'Dim result As Integer = dAdapter.Update(ReadingCsv)
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "fileFields(3)")` will pass "filefields(3)" as a string when you're really trying to pass the actual field.  When your insert is called, you're going to have to write some sort of a loop through your code and then you can insert it like:

```
INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
```

Where your value and columns correspond.  Now to get the CSV, save it as a variable (parse it from the text box included in this) or pass it back from the webpage.  Once you have it back, I'd create a class which holds your file field so you can read your code later then stick that into a list.  Iterate through that list and make a string.  I'd use a string builder because I think it's more readable.  Then you can drop your creating parameters and just call the strSql directly.  Does this make sense?

If this answer still helps you / you're curious about the actual code, comment and I'll write it but as it's a month old I'm assuming you solved your problem.